# psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Operation timed out Is the server running on host "***" and accepting TCP/IP

Tags: postgresql, nginx, vps, postgresql-15

I have a VPS server that I just installed Postgres in and set up. When I tried to connect remotely, I get the error:
**psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Operation timed out**
**Is the server running on host "31.187.72.253" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?**

My connection test is:

```
psql -h 31.187.72.253 -p 5432 -U postgres
```

Doing the above from the VPS terminal itself works.
But elsewhere, it doesn't.

My /etc/postgresql/15/main/postgresql.conf configuration is:

```
# - Connection Settings -                                                                               

listen_addresses = '*'                  # what IP address(es) to listen on;                             
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;                            
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all                      
                                        # (change requires restart)                                     
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)                                     
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)                                     
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)                                     
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of directories
```

My /etc/postgresql/15/main/pg_hba.conf configuration is:

```
        # Database administrative login by Unix domain socket                            
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD           

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only                             
local     all             all                                  peer
# IPv4 local connections:                                                        
host   all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:                                                        
host   all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the               
# replication privilege.                                                         
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               scram-sha-256
```

I am using the latest postgres:

```
root@user:/etc/postgresql/15/main# psql -V
psql (PostgreSQL) 15.3 (Ubuntu 15.3-1.pgdg22.04+1)
```

Port 5432 is not blocked:

```
root@user:/etc/postgresql/15/main# sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5433/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5432/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
5432                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
7080                       DENY        Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5432 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
5432/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
7080 (v6)                  DENY        Anywhere (v6)
```

With netstat:

```
root@user:/etc/postgresql/15/main# netstat -tuln | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

When I ping my VPS IP from inside the VPS or from another VPS server, it pings correctly. But trying to connect to postgres from these other VPS or my local system doesn't work.

PS: Pinging the VPS from my local system doesn't work too.

Please, how do I resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you check the connection using telnet from client to database server?

Comment: You have only shown that is not blocked by ufw on that box.  But it is being blocked by something, somewhere.

Comment: Yeah. I am yet to figure out what else is blocking it. I have not succeeded in connecting from another VPS, but trying to connect from my local system is still not possible, and hence I cannot connect from my nodejs application in development.

Comment: @UmutTEKİN when I tried telnet, I get this error: Trying 31.187.72.253...
telnet: connect to address 31.187.72.253: Operation timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host

Comment: I so much think this is a problem originating from my system because I can now successfully connect from other VPS